# How to get control back from defunct hosting company?

Tags: domains, web-hosting

We have a couple of websites hosted on Needa dot com that have recently disappeared and we cannot access any longer through Cpanel.

Is there a way we get control of our DNS records and web sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hosting service is gone, then your website's files are probably gone too. You may be able to get a cached copy from [the wayback machine](https://archive.org/web/) or from Google search, if it still shows up.

Regaining control of your domain name and DNS is more straightforward: you will need to log into your registrar. If you are unsure of the registrar of your domain, you can look it up [using this whois tool](https://whois.icann.org/en). Then log into (or get in contact with) your registrar to reassume control of your domain. You will need to set your NS records to point to nameservers under your control.